# Responsive Textview for different devices

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am trying to put a textview on a header in xamarin android.  I have used framelayout and then inside it i have used imageview as a header, then a textview over it, but the margin doesn't work same on tablets.

I have searched internet for the answers quite but could find any working support for that.

I cannot share the header image because of client privacy but here is my given code and a sample problem image. I have provided fixed width to textview because i want my text to wrap within that small box

[image]

```cs
    <FrameLayout
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/header"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="00:00 AM 00/00/0000"
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
         >

    </FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put the ImageView and TextView in a **RelativeLayout**

```
<RelativeLayout
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/header"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="55dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="00:00 AM 00/00/0000"
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:textSize="10sp"
    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
     >
</RelativeLayout>
```

Then set the position of the **TextView** and the **RelativeLayout** .

Comment: But Then i cannot use textview on top of image right?

Comment: Why wouldn't you be able to not use a TextView on top of the image, just because you are using RelativeLayout?

Comment: @MarioYT You can still set the TextView on top of Image .

Comment: i tried it its having the same issue the textview goes out of the image on different device

Comment: You can share a sample and I will check it on my side .